# Study the convergence or divergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sin n}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sin n}$$
convergent or not?

Comment: By Hurwitz theorem for rational approximation of irrational numbers, $|\pi - n/m| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}m^2}$ for infinitely many $n,m$. This implies $\frac{1}{|\sin n|} > Cn$ for infinitely many $n$ and, thus $\frac{1}{n \sin n}$ does not converge to $0$ so the series diverges.

Comment: @YuiTo Cheng: This is a great problem but not the best posed question for the site with no context/effort.

Comment: Can somebody give an elementary proof for $n\sin n \nrightarrow \infty$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @RRL what's $C_n$? Could you elaborate your proof,please?

Comment: @mengdie1928: Ok - below - I don't know of anything more elementary.

Comment: This type of series question -- with other powers $n^a (\sin n)^b$ as well  -- is always about to what extent $\sin n$ is repeatedly  close to $0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. There are series of this type where the convergence is unknown.  Read about the Flint Hills problem or look on this site. Not enough is known about the irrationality measure of $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $|\sin n| = |\sin(m\pi -n)| < |m\pi - n| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}m} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}n} \frac{n}{m} $ for infinitely many $n,m$, where the inequality follows from the Hurwitz rational approximation $|m\pi - n| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}m}$.

Again from the approximation $\frac{n}{m} < \pi + \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}m^2 } < \pi + 1$.

Thus,  $|\sin n| < \frac{\pi +1}{\sqrt{5}}\frac{1}{n}$ and $(n|\sin n|)^{-1}> \frac{\sqrt{5}}{\pi +1}$for infinitely many $n$. Hence, there is a subsequence of $\{(n\sin n)^{-1}\}$ that does not converge to $0$ and the series diverges.